# Yield a tuple or namedtuple in Python based on input

Tags: python-2.7, tuples, namedtuple

In Python 2.7 I had a function which takes in a tuple of iterables, maps each iterable to itertools.cycle, and then continuously yields new tuples. Similar to zip but it restarts each iterable instead of stopping. Everything was working fine until Raymond Hettinger convinced me to use more namedtuples. I converted my function over but I can't figure out the best way to handle both tuples and namedtuples. The problem is that namedtuple needs the individual arguments when initialized but tuple needs an iterable.

```
NT = namedtuple('NT', ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

x = [1,2]
y = ['a','b','c']
z = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']    

def var_gen(inputLists):
    tupleType = type(inputLists)
    cycles = map(itertools.cycle, inputLists)

    while 1:
        if tupleType is tuple:
            # No asterisk for tuple
            yield tuple(map(next, cycles))
        else:
            # With asterisk for namedtuple
            yield tupleType(*map(next, cycles))

gen = var_gen(NT(x,y,z))
for i in xrange(10):
    print next(gen)
```

The code above works for both tuples and namedtuples but it does not fit well with duck typing, it creates an extra check for each yield, and it feels like a bit of code smell to need a check and two lines which are identical except for a single asterisks. My actual function has some additional code inside the while loop so I do not want to remove the extra check per yield by creating two separate while loops.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this some more and namedtuple does have an `_make()` method which takes in an iterable and creates a namedtuple so the first yield statement could be:

```
yield iterType._make(map(next, cycles))
```

eliminating the asterisk but of course `list` and `tuple` do not have an `_make()` method so you still need an extra line. I could not figure out from the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Lib/collections.py) why it would be difficult to allow `MY_NAMED_TUPLE([iterable])` but there must be some reason.

This is the best solution I could develop. It only fixes my duck typing complaint but it does handle lists, tuples, namedtuples, and generators.

```
NT = namedtuple('NT', 'X Y Z')
NT_One = namedtuple('NT_One', 'Only')

x = [1,2]
y = ['a','b','c']
z = ['V','W','X','Y','Z']

def var_gen(inputLists):
    if iter(inputLists) is iter(inputLists):
        # Tests if inputLists is a generator
        iterType = tuple
    else:
        iterType = type(inputLists)
    cycles = map(itertools.cycle, inputLists)

    while 1:
        try:
            # This is the logic for a named tuple
            yield iterType(*map(next, cycles))
        except Exception:
            yield iterType(map(next, cycles))

test = []
test.append(var_gen(NT(x,y,z))) # namedtuple with multiple fields
test.append(var_gen(NT_One(x))) # namedtuple with only one field
test.append(var_gen((x,y,z)))   # regular tuple
test.append(var_gen([x,y,z]))   # list
test.append(var_gen((i for i in (x,y,z)))) # generator

for gen in test:
    print 'Next Test:'
    for i in xrange(10):
        print next(gen)
    print ' '
```

Comment: Turns out Giovanni Bajo also thought the constructor should be able to take an iterable. See his comment [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261-named-tuples/) with Steve Anderson providing a possible solution. Never took off though I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Does a single run of your program deal entirely with one or the other? If so, a pattern like this might be useful:

```
def var_gen_tuple():
    ...

def var_gen_namedtuple():
    ...

var_gen = var_gen_namedtuple

if tupleType is tuple:
    var_gen = var_gen_tuple

var_gen(...)
```

Comment: An interesting approach. My only problem with this is that all of the code in my function would have to be repeated twice and I am not good at remembering to fix bugs in two locations.